# PHP SQL query id from table with multiple values in rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue querying multiple values from rows that have a certain value.  I use the SQL code below to grab column "group_id"'s values if the "id" equals 999.  In the "xx_groupmap" table, the id 999 shows up three times with different values.  Below is my table.

```
table xx_groupmap
-------------------
id   |  group_id
-------------------
999  |  2
999  |  7
999  |  8
```

Below is the code I use

```
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = "SELECT group_id FROM xx_groupmap WHERE id = '999'";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
        foreach ($results as $t) {
        }
```

So in the end when I want to return the three values of id 999 I use this code

```
echo $t->group_id;
```

but it only outputs one number.  How do I build an array with the three values from id 999?

Answer (score 3):

Thats because, when you are in the foreach, `$t` is always updated, and you will get tha last `$t` only. Put them into an array.

```
$ids = array();
foreach ($results as $t) {
    $ids[] = $t->group_id;
}
var_dump($ids);
```